# is there different between calculate semantic similarity with wordnet by res_similarity or wup_similarity?

Tags: python

I want to calculate semantic similarity with wordnet between two word in python and saw different way to calculate similarity as follow: res_similarity, path_similarity, ...
I want to know are there different between this ways??
and my code is:

```
for word1 in list1:
for word2 in list2:
    wordFromList1 = wordnet.synsets(word1)
    wordFromList2 = wordnet.synsets(word2)
    s = wordFromList1[0].wup_similarity(wordFromList2[0])
```

Comment: Welcome to our community. If u want some help, please post some YOUR code first.

Answer (score 0):

resnik uses shared information content and path similarity normally counts the edges that separate both terms. Try some measures with wordnet here:
http://labs.fc.ul.pt/dishin/